# How to divide fields in Sub query and Sql Server Case Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am getting the error below on execution of query:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

My query is as follows:

```
CASE 
    WHEN GL.LDCategory IN ('21069','21070','21051','21073') THEN 
        CASE
            WHEN LDContractType = 'AMORT' THEN (SELECT TOTAL_PRFT / NO_OF_INSTALLMENT FROM InsightSource.BS.IS_H_LD_SCHEDULE)
            WHEN LDContractType = 'BULLET' THEN ISNULL(GL.LDSSAMOUNT,0) 
        END
END AS LDSSAMOUNT,
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear - that subquery isn't allowed to return more than one row. Show us a complete query!

Comment: @MAunAli, how many rows does InsightSource.BS.IS_H_LD_SCHEDULE contain?

Comment: A subquery is only allowed to return a single scalar value unless it's inside an `in` or `exists` clause.

Comment: The subquery needs to be correlated! I..e include a condition to the outer (main) table.

Answer (score 2):

The query causing the problem: `SELECT TOTAL_PRFT / NO_OF_INSTALLMENT FROM InsightSource.BS.IS_H_LD_SCHEDULE`. It must return one row of data only, yours is returning multiple.

Here there are two problems:

1- The one you stated in your question: Subquery can return more than 1 result. You need to set a "definer", to which data you want. For example: If you table is something like below:

```
ID Total_prft No_Of_Installment
1     15            3
2     20            5
```

Then you can do like: `SELECT TOTAL_PRFT / NO_OF_INSTALLMENT FROM InsightSource.BS.IS_H_LD_SCHEDULE WHERE ID = @ID`, where @ID is a pre-defined variable (maybe you can get it from your GL table).

Or, as it is recommended by @Suraj Kumar, you can use `TOP 1` keyword as well, if it works for you.

2- Another problem here is you are not checking if No_OF_Installment is null or zero, which will cause a division error. Please add a check by adding something like:

```
WHEN LDContractType = 'AMORT' THEN (
          case when NO_OF_INSTALLMENT IS NOT NULL AND NO_OF_INSTALLMENT > 0
               THEN SELECT TOTAL_PRFT / NO_OF_INSTALLMENT FROM InsightSource.BS.IS_H_LD_SCHEDULE
               ELSE 0 
          END)
...
```